# Chess Pieces not rendering correctly

Tags: java, chess

I am creating a chess game and I am now adding the pieces. All the pieces have rendered individually correctly, but now that I am trying to set them in their location they are not appearing where they should. What in my code is causing the pieces to generate wrong?

```
public class Tile {

Graphics g;

public static HashMap<HashMap<Integer, Integer>, String> pieces = new HashMap<>();

public Tile(Graphics g) {
    this.g = g;
}

public static void setPieceLoc(int x, int y, String tile) {

    x = (x*64) + 20;
    y = (y*64) + 20;
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> tileNum = new HashMap<>();
    tileNum.put(x, y);
    pieces.put(tileNum, tile);
}

public void tick() {
    registerPieces();
}

private static void registerPieces() {

    //Pawns
    for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {

        setPieceLoc(x, 1, "pawn");
        setPieceLoc(x, 6, "pawn");
    }

    for(int y = 0; y < 1; y++) {
        int cy = y*7;
        setPieceLoc(0, cy, "rook");
        setPieceLoc(1, cy, "knight");
        setPieceLoc(2, cy, "bishop");
        setPieceLoc(5, cy, "bishop");
        setPieceLoc(6, cy, "knight");
        setPieceLoc(7, cy, "rook");
    }

    setPieceLoc(3, 0, "queen");
    setPieceLoc(4, 0, "king");
    setPieceLoc(3, 0, "queen");
    setPieceLoc(4, 7, "king");

}

public void render(Graphics g) {
    for(HashMap<Integer, Integer> tile : pieces.keySet()) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for(Integer xy : tile.keySet()) {
            x = xy;
            y = tile.get(xy);
        }

        String piecesName = pieces.get(tile);

        g.drawImage(ChessImages.getPieceImage(piecesName), x, y, null);

    }

}

}
```

Here is what it is generating look like:

[image]

Comment: What are they appearing like.

Comment: There is an image link at the bottom.

Comment: That's what it **should** look like.  I am asking what you are getting.

Comment: My apology I mean that is what it is looking like as of now. It should generate like a regular chessboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is your pieces are black, and your board is black so you can't see them.

Unrelated, but you are using a HashMap to store coordinates of your pieces. This is completely unnecessary and I would recommend you use a Point.

Comment: I only used white pieces for now, so that can't get be it. Also I completely forgot about Point. That would have been useful to remember, but I added it now.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your white pieces?

Comment: Are you sure your white pieces are actually white and not transparent? It really stands out that they are only invisible over black squares.

Comment: Draw those pieces on a colored background like red.  This screenshot doesn't prove the pieces are white because they might be transparent, and just showing the background (white).

Comment: I will, but i am sure that the inside is blank white

Comment: Huh thats odd. When I change the color to Blue I can see the outline, but when I look at the file the color inside is pure white. Thanks

Comment: @TheGamerPlayz great. don't forget to accept this answer if it solved your question.